# How can you update a WPF Datagrid where ItemSource is a Linq-SQL collection that has .Refresh() executed on it?

Tags: wpf, linq, datagrid

I have a datagrid which has its ItemsSource bound to the result of a linq query (.ToList())

I can make changes to properties of the collection bound to the itemssource, and these changes are reflected immediately in the datagrid fields, such as;

```
myQueryList[2].myProperty = newValue
```

What I can't do though, is see the changes made in the database reflected in the datagrid by this;

```
myQueryList.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, myQueryList[2])
```

I have inspected the value of myQueryList[2].myProperty after this refresh, and it shows it has correctly updated from the database.  Why does the datagrid not display it, and how can i get the datagrid to display it?

Also; I have found the same problem with using an ObservableCollection

Comment: seems to have something with myQueryList.Refresh not activating the item's OnPropertyChanged() event.  If i force an OnPropertyChanged to occur for the changed property, the datagrid updates.  I guess its now a matter of determining what properties were changed with the .Refresh()...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Casey's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/92846/casey-gay) (edited) response in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613428/datacontext-refresh-and-propertychanging-propertychanged-events) post, i've found a workaround

I've implemented the SendPropertiesChanged() on the collection members and call it whenever i do a Refresh()

Answer (score 0):

Once you convert a `query` (deffered/dynamic) to a `collection` (fixed) using `ToList()` method, a separate collection is created. This new collection has no connection to the query. When something changes in query, it does not reflect on collection. You will need to reset the `ItemsSource` property whenever you call `Refresh()` on query.